# tkinter Toplevel objext is not callable

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, toplevel

good evening guys, I've been having trouble lately with tkinter windows. I have a program in which the users can "buy" stuff from stores, after adding the wanted products to the cart, a button takes them to the "final" review of the order, in which they can remove items they don't want, the problem is, I need to destroy that window, display the information window saying that "the item you didn't wanted has been removed from your cart", and run the "final preview" again (with the new data, AKA without the undesirable item). Problem is, after destroying the window, an error appears saying:

```
TypeError: 'Toplevel' object is not callable
```

The structure of my code is something like this:

```
def reviewwindow(*previous window*,cartlist):
    previuswindow.destroy()
    reviewwindow=Toplevel(gui)
    reviewwindow.title("cart review")
    reviewwindow.geometry("450x450")
    #code about the stuff I need to do#
    botonb= Button(reviewwindow, text = "Delete items",command=lambda:       deleteitems(reviewwindow,*previous window*,cartlist,delete), width=7)
botonb.grid(row=8,column=1)

def deleteitems(reviewwindow,*previous window*,cartlist,delete):
   reviewwindow.destroy()
   deleteitems=Toplevel(gui)
   deleteitems.title("delete")
   deleteitems.geometry("300x300")

#code##code#
boton= Button(deleteitems, text = "go back",command=lambda:reviewwindow(*previous window*,new_cartlist), width=9)
boton.grid(row=2,column=1)
```

I don't know if I made my problem clear enough, I you need more explanations or something I'll gladly provide more.

Comment: What's `*previous window*`? Does it have a proper name in your actual code?

Comment: yes it does, I have a ton of windows in the code, that window has the button that calls this window, I'm justimporting the  window name for the sake of destroying it when the new window pops up

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a function called `reviewwindow`, but then you assign `Toplevel(gui)` to `reviewwindow`. Same goes for `deleteitems`. When you call those functions, the program tries to call a `Toplevel` object, and those aren't callable. Choose unique names for every unique value.

Comment: ohhh I see, I thought toplevel was the only way to create a new window within another window

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with how you create new top-level windows, it has to do with how you named them. You defined functions with certain names, and then you assigned completely new values to their references. After that, they will point to the new objects rather than to the functions. When you try to treat those objects as functions (calling them), it fails.